# Почему jsoup не парсит конкретный сайт?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Использую стандартные конструкции по работе с jsoup:

```
Document mydoc = null;//Здесь хранится будет разобранный html документ
try {
     //Считываем страницу
     mydoc = Jsoup.connect(httpAddress).get();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     //Если не получилось ссчитать
     Log.wtf("maratsoftTAG", "Эксепшн!");
     }
//Получаем заголовок
mytitle = mydoc.title();
```

И не могу распарсить сайт http://mirfactov.com/, он просто возвращает пустоту разным методам библиотеки jsoup, не только .title(), но и .select(), и .getElementsByTag() и другим. При этом остальные сайты парсятся на ура.
В чем тут хитрость?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот сайт хочет две вещи:

1. Установленная кука `beget=begetok`;
2. Классика жанра - установленный UserAgent.

   ```
   mydoc = Jsoup.connect(httpAddress)
       .userAgent("Mozilla")
       .cookie("beget", "begetok")
       .get();
   ```

Чтобы до этого дойти, сто́ило посмотреть на трафик от браузера и от вашего приложения. Сравнительный анализ дает вышеприведенный результат.